# How many mapreduce jobs will run if i query a partitioned table in hive

Tags: hadoop

This may seems a little silly. But just want to know the exact answer. Suppose I've a table with 2 partitions. If a run a query against one partitioned column how many map jobs will run in the background.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've read that the # of mappers is determined based on the formula: (size of input divided by block size).  Block size for Hadoop 2 is 128 MB.

Therefore I assume you could divide the size of the files in that partition by 128 MB.

Answer (score 0):

So this depends on two things:

1. By default with non-splittable files, Hadoop will run a Map task for each input file. So if your partition folder has 100 input files, it will run 100 mappers. This would be the default for tab delimited text files for example.
2. If your files are splittable, it will split based on your blocksize settings. This requires you to use a splittable file format like sequence files.

It's easiest to reason about if you just use simple flat-files. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help Matthew

Comment: You're welcome! With regular MapReduce jobs you can specify the number of Mappers and Reducers, but hive sort of does it's own thing because it runs multiple MapReduce jobs.